# Using masonry plugin with infinite scroll, callback function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Im working on a tumblr site that uses infinite scroll along with masonry.

The scroll plugin is called externally from a third party, and I trigger the masonry plugin on page load...

```
  $(window).load(function(){

    $('.autopagerize_page_element').masonry();  

  });
```

The problem is that when the scroll pulls in more data the masonry no longer works, has anybody had this problem before?

Comment: You probably know this but there is a working demo here: http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html  It uses a `$(document).ready()` initialisation with a call to the imagesLoaded plugin, which I guess is the same intent as using `$(window).load()`, but not sure what the implementation implications are of one vs the other.

Comment: Yeah Ive tried this already @leftclickben, thanks